# Define shared or fresh fixture on test method level with TestNG (or any other framework)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

What I want to do is

1. define dependencies on test methods (TestNG)
2. define for each test method if the test fixture is shared (not reset) or re-created before the test method runs

See the following example:

1. *test1* would be run first
2. if *test1* succeeds then *test2* is run and uses the same data that *test1* inserted
3. if *test2* succeeds then *test3* is run and uses the date from *test1* and *test2*
4. if *test3* succeeds then *test4* is run but *test4* starts with a clean state, it will not share the same fixture

   ```
   public class SomeTestClass extends Insertable {
   @BeforeSuite
   public void background() {
       insert(0);
   }

   @Test()
   public void test1() {

       // when
       insert(1);

       // then
       assertThatIsContained(0);
       assertThatIsContained(1);
   }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test1"})
   @SharedFixture
   public void test2() {
       // when
       insert(2);

       // then
       assertThatIsContained(0);
       assertThatIsContained(1);
       assertThatIsContained(2);
   }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test2"})
   @SharedFixture
   public void test3() {
       // when
       insert(3);

       // then
       assertThatIsContained(0);
       assertThatIsContained(1);
       assertThatIsContained(2);
       assertThatIsContained(3);
   }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test2"})
   @FreshFixture
   public void test4() {
       // given
       insert(99);

       // when
       insert(4);

       // then
       assertThatIsNotContained(1);
       assertThatIsNotContained(2);
       assertThatIsNotContained(3);
       assertThatIsContained(0);
       assertThatIsContained(99);
       assertThatIsContained(4);
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your tests in two [groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) (by specifying the `groups` property within the `@Test` annotation) and annotate your initialization method with [`@BeforeGroups`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/BeforeGroups.html) to make it run only once per group.

To make your groups execute in a certain order, use `dependsOnGroups` in your `@Test` annotation.

A more straight-forward approach to achieve the same is to split your methods in two classes (say `Test1` and `Test2`) and define a `@BeforeClass`-annotated method in your `Insertable` superclass which cleans up your repository (by invoking `clear()` or `truncate()` or whatever) before the test methods in each class will get executed.

Comment: ok, that sounds good, so I make two groups (maybe in different classes) one that does setup the test preconditions only once in the @BeforeGroups and the other before each test method runs. I like that.

Comment: I assumed you wanted those methods to be in the same class. I'll edit my answer to cover the two classes approach.

Comment: IMO both options are good (same class vs different classes) but I think I will go for having one class with different groups. Thank you for your edit.